# How do you use ES6 exports in Cloudflare worker scripts?

Tags: javascript, cloudflare-workers

I'm trying to get familiar with CloudFlare workers.

I've copied a quickstart project from https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/get-started/quickstarts, via:

```
wrangler generate my-app https://github.com/cloudflare/worker-template
```

This gives me a JS file that listens for "fetch" and returns a `Response` via `handleRequest`:

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

async function handleRequest(request) {
  return new Response('Hello worker!', {
    headers: { 'content-type': 'text/plain' },
  })
}
```

Ok, that makes sense.

Now I want to include one of [Cloudflare's examples](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/examples/return-html)

```
export default {
  fetch() {
    const html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
      <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p>This markup was generated by a Cloudflare Worker.</p>
      </body>
    `;
    return new Response(html, {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "text/html;charset=UTF-8",
      },
    });
  },
};
```

This makes less sense. Am I supposed to replace all of the original code with that? If I do, I get an error on `wrangler publish`:

> Error: Something went wrong with the request to Cloudflare... No event
> handlers were registered. This script does nothing.

Am I supposed to mash them together somehow? How? Is there a step or configuration I'm missing?

Comment: Can you share the file structure you are using and if you are importing the second file somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two code snippets in your question use two different syntaxes supported by Workers: Service Workers syntax and ES Modules syntax. `addEventListener` is used with Service Workers syntax, which was the original syntax supported by Workers. More recently, Workers added support for a new ES-modules-based syntax, which uses `export default` to export handlers. This new syntax avoids some boilerplate (no weird `event.respondWith()`) and has some other advantages.

You need to specify in your `wrangler.toml` which syntax you are using. To use modules syntax, you'll need to add:

```
[build.upload]
format = "modules"
main = "./worker.mjs"
```

[See more documentation here.](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/cli-wrangler/configuration#build)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you are supposed to mash them together.
Putting it simply according to the guide [here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/get-started/guide#5a-understanding-hello-world)

> Fundamentally, a Workers application consists of two parts:
>
> An event listener that listens for FetchEvents, and An event handler
> that returns a Response object which is passed to the event’s
> .respondWith() method.

Just editing the first example so you understand easily

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

async function handleRequest(request) {
  const html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>This markup was generated by a Cloudflare Worker.</p>
  </body>`;
  return new Response(html, {
    headers: { "content-type": "text/html;charset=UTF-8" },
  })
}
```

Comment: This would be still Service Workers syntax, so downvoted.